# Can I create a form dynamically

Tags: install4j

I have created a configurable screen in my installer but want to add elements to it dynamically
Is it possible to dynamically add elements to a screen?
any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 5.1.x, this is not possible.